# Add points to a circle

Tags: python-3.x

I constructed a large uniform circle (dots = 8000000) in python 3. In the next step, I would like to add additional dots (in myList) outside the circle but at the corresponding position.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

circleSize = 8000000
myList = [155744, 213230, 215537, 262274, 262613, 6143898, 244883, 509516, 1997259, 2336382]


fig = plt.figure(figsize=(4, 4))
n_dots = circleSize   # set number of points in circle
uniformSpacing = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, n_dots)  # create uniform spacing between points
center_x, center_y = (50, 20)  # set the center of the circle
x_coord, y_coord = [], []    # for coordinates of points to plot
radius = 10.0          # set the radius of circle

for items in uniformSpacing :
    x = center_x + radius*np.cos(items)
    y = center_y + radius*np.sin(items)
    x_coord.append(x) 
    y_coord.append(y)   

plt.scatter(x_coord, y_coord, c = 'black', s=1)  # plot points 
plt.show()
```

[image]

How can I add the points to my plot?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you need to plot the circle and the new points in the same `scatter` call? Multiple calls to `pyplot` will add new plots on to the same figure.

Comment: No, multiple calls are also fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you're coming from a MATLAB background, `pyplot` has `hold on` by default, so you can do multiple `plot()` or `scatter()` calls without it erasing what was on the plot before.

Also, since you're already using numpy, you should utilize its vectorization capabilities and calculate `x_coord` and `y_coord` using SIMD instructions rather than looping and appending to a Python list (which is painfully slow).

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(4, 4))
n_dots = circleSize   # set number of points in circle
uniformSpacing = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, n_dots)  # create uniform spacing between points
center_x, center_y = (50, 20)  # set the center of the circle
radius = 10.0          # set the radius of circle
x_coord = center_x + radius * np.cos(uniformSpacing)
y_coord = center_y + radius * np.sin(uniformSpacing)

plt.scatter(x_coord, y_coord, marker='o', color='k');

new_dots_angles = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 5)
new_radius = 15.0
new_xcoord = center_x + new_radius * np.cos(new_dots_angles)
new_ycoord = center_y + new_radius * np.sin(new_dots_angles)

plt.scatter(new_xcoord, new_ycoord, marker='*', color='r')
```

Comment: Why "hold on"? I thought that pyplot always acts as if hold was set to True and that everything before plt.show() is added to the plot. If I use your plt.scatter('ok'): I get the TypeError: "ufunc 'sqrt' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''. 
Can you please show your solution based on my example? Thank you!

Comment: `'ok'` and `'*r'` are matlab-like ways of setting the color and marker. Apparently they don't work with `pyplot.scatter()` like they do with `pyplot.plot()`

Comment: You _don't_ need `hold on.`. pyplot behaves as if hold was set to True by default.